# Obtaining number of rows written to multiple targets in Informatica Power Center

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement where I need to obtain the number of rows written to multiple targets in my mapping. There are 3 targets in my mapping (T1, T2 and T3). I need the number of rows written to each target separately. These values need to be used in subsequent sessions.
I understand that there is a method where I can use separate counters and write them to a flat file and perform a lookup on this file in subsequent mappings. However, I am looking for a direct and better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $PMTargetName@numAffectedRows built-in variables. In your case it would be something like

- $PMT1@numAffectedRows
- $PMT2@numAffectedRows
- $PMT3@numAffectedRows

Please refer [An ETL Framework for Operational Metadata Logging](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html) for details.

Comment: I have something very similar to the question only difference being that my mapping as two instances of same table i-e A1 and A2 both are target table instances while A is a single table . A1 is insert while A2 is update , while  $PMA1@numAffectedRows represent Inserted rows for my table A , While $PMA2@numAffectedRows represent updated rows for table A ?

Comment: Yes, @Faizan, exactly. Whatever is there between $PM and @ refers to Target Name. Underneath it can be the very same table, as you can use the Target multiple times in the mapping.